# Installing Solaris 10 on Sun oracle SPARC Enterprise T5220 and Sun oracle SPARC T4-1 server

Tags: installation, oracle, solaris-10, sunos

I m newbie to sever environment.I got old Solaris 5.10 already installed following severs

1. Sun oracle SPARC Enterprise T5220
2. Sun oracle SPARC T4-1 server

It does not show BIOS loading ,when it is booting up.It shows the installed operating system is loading and come to SUNSP login: prompt.I reseted the password of T5220 server by jumper reset.Then it comes to console login.The problem is I do not know any password to go beyond that point and the people who gave me did not have a password history.(These were donated for educational purpose).So that I need to reset the severs and install new operating system.I tried to install Oracle Solaris 10 (SPARC) with (OK command prompt : boot cdrom -s) .but it shows

The file just loaded does not appear to be executable
or
Can't open boot device

I burn DVDs with Nero and Alcohol 120 softwares. But I failed.I tried several command with DVD ROM to check whether it is working or not.It is fine.I can not understand what is the reason which I failed.Please help me with this.

Comment: Are you sure you download the right version of Solaris 10? Because there is version for x86 and version for Spark.

Comment: I downloaded from this link (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris10/downloads/index.html) the first ISO image for -Oracle Solaris 10 (SPARC).

Comment: I use PuTTy software  which is installed in my laptop to connect to the console of the sever through serial management port.I do not use a sun keyboard.It may be a reason not to identify commands correctly ..?

Comment: Did you check the checksum of downloaded file?

Comment: No....I will check it now

Comment: Yes..I got the same hash value as in download page....

Comment: You can try to run in text mode from your terminal with command `boot cdrom - nowin` from OK prompt

Comment: It show Can not read disk label. Can not open disk label package.Error: boot-read fail. Can not open boot device.

Comment: In such case seems like your DVD is not created properly.

Comment: I tried  burning operating system to DVD in many ways.but same response as can not read disk....can not open disk and Error:boot read-fail

Comment: Is there any specific way to burn it....?

Comment: It must be burn as image. Not extract and copy files

Comment: @RehanThilakarathna any news ?

Comment: I am very sorry for late...It was actually image burning problem...but there is another problem,sometimes console cable not detecting and screen stuck not showing any response...Thank you Romeo Ninov

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds to me like you are in the ILOM. The way that the 5220 server works is there is a ILOM that is like a management interface. You have to tell it to boot from the cdrom and that will initiate the installer.